# best way to query more than 1Million Records from a MongoDB Collection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, mongotemplate

Please find my sample documents from mongoDB below:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581907"),
        "_class" : "sample.model.User",
        "name" : "Eric",
        "DOJ" : "2012-01-22 08:09:20.000",
        "age" : 45
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581908"),
        "_class" : "sample.model.User",
        "name" : "Antony",
        "DOJ" : "2011-07-22 08:09:20.000",
        "age" : 33
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55c0e5e5511f0a164a581909"),
        "_class" : "sample.model.User",
        "name" : "Alice",
        "DOJ" : "2018-05-01 08:16:20.000",
        "age" : 35
    }
]
```

I have million of records like this in my collection. I need to an efficient way to query it based on the DOJ date where there is a possibility that I may get more than a million records for the same DOJ date. Please find the sample code which I used to fetch the records using mongoTemplate below:

```
Criteria criteria = new Criteria().andOperator(Criteria.where("DOJ").gte("2018-01-01 08:10:00.000"), Criteria.where("DOJ").lte("2020-01-01 08:10:00.000"));
Query query = new Query(criteria);
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query,User.class);
```

If the results returned is more than 100,000 records than I need to have a pagination with records grouped by each DOJ or if it has 100,000 on the same DOJ date then I must have an logic to group it based on each hour. Any help is highly appreciated..

Comment: Side note: The contents of a Mongo collection are not records, but _documents_.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thanks for the note

Comment: I think you can first get a count on it since you have different logics over that criteria. Then You need to get documents page by page. if you need all of them at once then I think there is no other way to make it faster (except adding indexes).